# How do I write a ClearCase trigger that launches a batch script?

Tags: triggers, clearcase

I am an extreme novice when it comes to ClearCase triggers but I am very used to working with ClearCase.

I would like to write a trigger that will fire when a user checks in a file and launch a batch script that is on the ClearCase server.  I assume that the trigger will somehow provide me the ID of the activity that is being used and the stream as parameters, so I need to learn how to use these.

Where can I find a tutorial?  I've found some documentation but it doesn't really help me.  I need a step-by-step sort of guide both for programming (with code examples) and for setting it.

Thank you!

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a postop checkin trigger, and you can see some of them in the "[IBM Rational ClearCase: The ten best triggers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4311.html)" page:

```
cleartool mktrtype -c "Trigger to check the checkin" -element -all -postop checkin -execwin "ccperl \\server\triggers\check_checkin.bat" -execunix "Perl /net/server/triggers/check_checkin.pl" CHECK_CHECKIN
```

You can see all the environment variables you can use in a script launched by a trigger in the page "[mktrtype](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm)".
It includes:

- `CLEARCASE_ACTIVITY`: The UCM activity, if applicable, involved in the operation that caused the trigger to fire.
  For checkin, checkout, and uncheckout operations, the activity that is set in the view used for the operation.
- `CLEARCASE_STREAM`: The UCM stream containing the object involved in the action that caused the trigger to fire, if applicable.

Note: the [OP Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1999794/andrew) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745580/how-do-i-write-a-clearcase-trigger-that-launches-a-batch-script/14745896#comment20671598_14745896) that:

> The `CLEARCASE_STREAM` EV is only valid for All `deliver`, `rebase` and `mkbl` operations; `mkactivity`, `chactivity`, `rmactivity`, `setactivity`, `mkstream`, `chstream`, `rmstream`, `chbl`, and `rmbl` operations.
>   With the `checkin` operation it returns `NULL`.

In that case, you could use the `CLEARCASE_VIEW_TAG` EV in order to get the stream name:

```
 # Windows Syntax
cleartool lsstream -view %CLEARCASE_VIEW_TAG%
 # Unix Syntax
cleartool lsstream -view $CLEARCASE_VIEW_TAG
```

Comment: thanks for the links, I will take a look.  From what I understand, the trigger will fire on the PC that is performing the checkin through CCRC and not on the ClearCase server, which is why you have to put the `\\server` path to the trigger.  Is this correct?  Also, if I have `"ccperl \\server\triggers\check_checkin.bat"` would that directly run the batch file?  In all of the examples on the site you sent even though there is .bat specified there is always a perl script.

Comment: @Andrew Wait, are you using CCRC? `cleartool mktrtype` is only available on a full ClearCase installation. The idea of the \\server is: the script can be anywhere, provided it is a a path accessible from the ClearCase server. The script will be executed on the ClearCase server even though it may reside elsewhere. If you execute the ccperl yourself, you won't have then environment variables I mentioned properly setup.

Comment: the idea is to have a trigger fire on the server once a user performs checkin through CCRC.  I want it to run a batch file that takes environment variables as parameters.

Comment: @Andrew so you should define your trigger on the ClearCase server. Agan, that script can be stored anywhere as long as the server can access it. It will be executed on the server.

Comment: I am trying to do a very simple trigger test that assigns a trigger to a stream `cleartool mktrtype -element -postop checkin -execwin "\\server\folder\test.bat" -stream <stream>@\<vob> -nc TRIGGERTEST` but I get the error `Error: Object is in unexpected VOB: "<stream>@\<vob>".` I ran the command from inside my view.  Where am I supposed to run the command?

Comment: You can run the command anywhere, but you need to use a pvob, both for the stream, and the name of the vob (not pvob) for the name of your trigger.

Comment: @Andrew see my previous comment. The examples of the 10 best scripts   don't mention a vob after the name of the trigger because they are executing the command directly in the vob within a view.

Comment: after mktrtype do I have to associate it using mktrigger such as described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14271853)?

Comment: @Andrew yes, you can attach it to the vob: vob:\yourvob

Comment: I've done `cleartool mktrtype -element -all -postop checkin -execwin "\\server\folder\trigger.bat" -stream <stream>@\<pvob> TRIGGERTEST@\<vob>` but I get the error `Error: Object is in unexpected VOB: "<stream>@\<pvob>"`.  I have run the command from both any location and from a dynamic view pointing to the stream that I want to create it on.  No luck.  Do you have any suggestions?  If I don't specify a stream, the trigger gets applied to the entire vob, but I want to limit it to a specific stream.

Comment: @Andrew you can try specifying the full name of that stream, using the object-selector form: stream:streamname@\avob . Note that \vob is the Windows notation.

Comment: @Andrew I missed the -ucm parameter! Only a UCM trigger-type will accept a range-restriction parameter like -stream.

Comment: As far as I understand it, UCM trigger types will not allow the `-postop checkin` argument. When I use the `stream:` selector i get `Error: Unexpected object selector kind:`.  In this case, how can I use the `-ucmobject` but still use it on checkin?

Comment: @Andrew I didn't see that restriction when looking at  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm . But if that the case, I would recommend to simplify, apply it to all elements (and not just to a stream), and use that `CLEARCASE_STREAM` environment variable to decide if the script should accept/deny the action, or simply accept because the element is checked-in in another stream than the one expected.

Comment: I had that idea too, but alas the `CLEARCASE_STREAM` EV is only valid for `All deliver, rebase and mkbl operations; mkactivity, chactivity, rmactivity, setactivity, mkstream, chstream, rmstream, chbl, and rmbl` operations.  With the `checkin` operation it returns `NULL`.  I am currently exploring the `lsactivity` command to see the stream that the activity is attached to.  That way the trigger can be applied to all, but filtered afterwards to a stream.

Comment: @Andrew if you have the name of the view, you can do a `cleartool lsstream -view view-tag`: it will give you the name of the stream. I have edited the answer to make that more visible.

Comment: That's a useful command, thanks.  `lsstream -s` will give just the stream.  Do you know whether you can add `@\<pvob>` at the end of that somehow?  As an aside, why do all these commands give you *almost* exactly what you need? :)

Comment: @Andrew you can deduced the pvob by adding the `-l` option to the `lsstream` command: `cleartool lsstream -l -view view-tag`: That would require a grep though.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I opted for the `lsactivity` approach since it's easier to read through.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers always execute at the client side, not on the server. 
ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/presentations/ruc99_pres/supplementccm28coverf/triggertips.html